# Uninstalling torrix/laravel-uikit

Tags: laravel, dependencies, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I've recently found a [Laravel-UIKit preset](https://github.com/torrix/laravel-uikit), and I know it strictly noted there that It should only be used on a fresh install and not be added to an existing project, but silly me, I still added it anyway.

Now my project seems not to work the way it used to. I've tried removing all the installed files and removing dependencies manually. I even switched back to my old Git branch to make my project work again. However, now it just gives me an error saying the following.

> ```
> Class 'Torrix\LaravelUikitServiceProvider' not found
>
>
>
> at C:\Users\user1\Desktop\general_workspace\workspaces\myproj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:690
>     686▕      * @return \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
>     687▕      */
>     688▕     public function resolveProvider($provider)
>     689▕     {
>   ➜ 690▕         return new $provider($this);
>     691▕     }
>     692▕
>     693▕     /**
>     694▕      * Mark the given provider as registered.
>
>   1 C:\Users\user1\Desktop\general_workspace\workspaces\myproj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:624
>       Illuminate\Foundation\Application::resolveProvider("Torrix\LaravelUikitServiceProvider")
>
>   2   C:\Users\user1\Desktop\general_workspace\workspaces\myproj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:75
>       Illuminate\Foundation\Application::register("Torrix\LaravelUikitServiceProvider")
> ```

How can I solve this issue? Is there any way to revert to my project state where `torrix/laravel-uikit` was not installed?

Comment: try clearing the service provider caches , might be in `boostrap/cache` then run a `composer dump-autoload` as well to recreate it with the exiting dependencies

Comment: @apokryfos Holy cheeze, almost 3 hours of pulling my hair out. this is what solved my problem. In my case its in `bootsrap/cache/services.php` and then `composer dump-autoload`. Thanks man, you're a saviour!